# TypeScript: get the type of a nested object

Tags: typescript, types

I know that this question may have been answered elsewhere but in case it wasn't, can someone help me get the type of a nested object? We're talking about an object that has multiple other object but all of them look pretty much the same.

```
const VALUES = {
    currentStreak: {
      display: "Current streak",
      value: currentStreak,
    },
    longestStreak: {
      display: "Longest streak",
      value: longestStreak,
    },
    contributionsThisYear: {
      display: "Contributions this year",
      value: contributionsThisYear,
    },
    totalContributions: {
      display: "Total contributions",
      value: totalContributions,
    },
    currentCompany: {
      display: "Working at",
      value: currentCompany,
    },
}
```

This would be the object and this is what I've got. It works well for the main keys but I want to have the keys of each object typed as well.

```
export type Something = {
  [key in keyof typeof VALUES]: { [key: string]: string | number };
};
```

How do I get the second part right? So that each object has `display` and `value` with `value` being a number or a string.

Sorry if this is a repeat! I'm hoping to understand this once and for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Something` is supposed to be a type for `VALUES`, then you have a problem because you are referencing the object you want to type in its own type declaration.

Unless you have some sort of `Enum` with string values to extract the keys from, you should be typing the keys as just `string`s:

```js
interface innerSomething {
  display: string
  value: number | string
}

type Something = {
  [key in string]: innerSomething
}
```

With an `Enum` it should be something like this:

```js
enum SomethingKeys {
    currentStreak,
    longestStreak,
    contributionsThisYear,
    totalContributions,
    currentCompany
}

interface innerSomething {
  display: string
  value: number | string
}

type Something = {
  [key in keyof typeof SomethingKeys]: innerSomething;
}
```

You could also not declare the interface and declare the type of the inner objects in the actual `Something` declaration like:

```js
enum SomethingKeys {
    currentStreak,
    longestStreak,
    contributionsThisYear,
    totalContributions,
    currentCompany
}

type Something = {
  [key in keyof typeof SomethingKeys]: { display: string, value: number | string };
}
```

Although using an interface is more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly define the second part

```
type DataPoint = {
  display: string;
  value: number;
};

export type Something = {
  [key in keyof typeof VALUES]: DataPoint;
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that dynamically?

Comment: @dragi as a best practice you should have your variables definition be dictated by your types. If you want to get the exact type of a variable, you can just `type Something = typeof VALUES` (this will match all of the keys and value as they are)

Answer (score -1):

```
typeof VALUES[keyof typeof VALUES]
```

Comment: Your answer is not clear